# different type of exception handlings by using single try block and exquisite in single time

Tags: exception

we have different types of exceptions for array expression and intiger expression one by one I need to handle the both exception one by one at a time by using single try block ....please give me  answer

Comment: You should provide sample code to help others help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java code, you may try this:

```
try{
    // do your operation here
} catch( Exception e ){
    if( e instanceof ArrayExpressionException ){
        // handle it
    }
    else if( e instanceof IntegerExpressionException ){
        // handle it
    }
    else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The type of the exception declared in the catch block doesn't have to be java.lang.Exception. It has to be a type that is a common supertype of both ArrayExpressionException and IntegerExpressionException, though. It could be ExpressionException, for instance, if it exists.